# Completely clearing a text file

Tags: lua

Well, the name is self explanatory. I don't know how to go along with it and I don't want to risk breaking the script by deleting the file and replacing it.

Can anyone post a method I could use? I tried searching around and so far no luck.

Comment: `io.open(filename,"w"):close()`

Comment: you don't want to risk breaking the script? what? you could a) create a backup of your script and b) not try this with your 10000 lines of code life's work...

Answer (score 3):

Posting [Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff)'s comment as an answer.

Use

```
io.open(filename,"w"):close()
```

where `filename` is the name of the file you want to clear. This will open the file for writing and immediately close the file, discarding its contents.